# Working back a regex to form new input strings

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression like:

```
/items\/a=(0-9)+\/b=(0-9)+/
```

which matches urls like:

```
items/a=5/b=5,
items/a=11/b=9
```

I hope the regex is correct, but please do not mind if it is not.

What I want to be able to do is injecting values back into this regexp so lets say I have `a=99, b=99` for values and I want to work out the string `items/a=99/b=99`. It can be done manually with string operations but is there a way to do this using the regex pattern itself?

The reason I want to do this is I am trying to write a routing method for a front controller. Assuming I match the url
`/product/3` to `controller = ProductController`, `action = display`, `id=3`. I want to be able to create the url back using a function `createUrl($controller, $action, $params)` from the regex.

I hope it was clear, my English is not very good so sorry on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to find out offset for each group in your expression and then insert substrings at specific offsets (starting from the end of the string)

```
    $re = '/items\/a=([0-9])+\/b=([0-9])+/';
    $str = 'items/a=5/b=6';

    $replacements = array(1 => 123, 2 => 456);

    preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); 

    for($i = count($matches) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $p = $matches[$i];
        $str = substr_replace($str, $replacements[$i], $p[1], strlen($p[0]));
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant to change his regex to `([0-9]+)` rather than `([0-9])+` in order to conform with your matching requirements.